# Overzealous auto-wiring of spring bean properties in grails

Tags: spring, grails

I have a domain class:

```
class Searcher  {
    String names
    List<String> getExperiments() {
        return names.split(',');
    }

    void setExperiments(List<String> list) {
         names = list.join(',');
    }
}
```

and a bean defined in the resource file

```
experiments(com.fxpal.querium.experiment.ExperimentHolder) {
    otherProp = 'foo'
}
```

The `experiments` bean is semantically different from the `experiments` property of the `Searcher` class. 
How do I prevent Spring from auto-wiring a specific property of a specific bean? Since the `experiments` property of the `Searcher` bean is derived, I don't want Spring to touch it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just name your bean experimentHolder? By default its going to auto wire by name.

Comment: The basic question is how to prevent auto-wiring for specific properties. It seems like this should be possible. It's also interesting that all bean names are in the same logical namespace, so combining classes from different libraries can create naming conflicts. Or is there a way around that?